# Types of Uncertainty

Tags: statistics, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

There are three types of uncertainty. How can one illustrate different between fuzzy uncertainty, resolution uncertainty, and probability uncertainty?

Comment: Could you provide a reference telling what these are? Google turned out surprisingly unhelpful when I tried to find this out.

Comment: In this paper you can find a example of these types [Measuring Fuzzy Uncertainty](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=277960)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example in the second section (introduction) of [Measuring Fuzzy Uncertainty](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=277960) .